# MySQL Table Alias - Any security advantages?

Tags: mysql

Quick question, any ideas why Drupal views would construct queriers like the snippet below:

```
LEFT JOIN {taxonomy_index} field_product_category_taxonomy_term_data__taxonomy_index ON field_product_category_taxonomy_term_data.nid = field_product_category_taxonomy_term_data__taxonomy_index.nid
```

Why not just:

```
LEFT JOIN taxonomy_index ON field_product_category_taxonomy_term_data.nid = taxonomy_index.nid
```

Would make it much easier to read or are there security advantages, etc?

Thanks

Comment: In general I find aliases greatly overused. They should really only be used to disambiguate. And why not just `LEFT JOIN taxonomy_index USING (nid)`?

Answer (score 0):

Drupal likely doesn't it because it was easier than developing Alisa logic. There really would be not advantage to that additional step - so why bother.

Alias have no security advantage (except obscurity)